# Can’t access a property of an object stored in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I console.log(this.state.dossier) it returns the object with a lot of properties. But when I console.log(this.state.dossier.code) it returns undefined.

How can i render the properties?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Client extends Component {
  state = {
    dossier: []
  };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const req = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/dossier/EQDOM/D200074`);
    const doss = await JSON.stringify(req);
    this.setState({ dossier: doss });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {this.state.dossier.length > 0 && (
          <div>

            <span>code: {this.state.dossier.code}</span>

          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Client;
```

Comment: Are you sure that "code" in there? Can you inspect the network request and check the response? Nobody can help you with those few informations

Comment: Please post the json data that you are receiving from `http://localhost:3000/api/dossier/EQDOM/D200074` too.

Comment: Using `fetch()` incorrectly

Comment: @AndrewL  here is the data:    [{"ID":34404198,"AGENCE":"1.1.9.","CODE":"EQDOM/D200074","DTCLOTURE":null,"DTCONSTITUTIONDP":null,"DTCREATION":null,"DT_INIT":"2018-11-01T07:36:39.000Z","DT_MAJ":"2018-12-03T23:00:00.000Z","DTMISEAJOUR":null,"DTRECEPTIONPIECES":null,"DTREMISEDOSSIER":null,"UTILISATEUR_ID":568574,"INDBCENTRALISATIONAUTO":null,"INDCLOTURE":null,"NOTEDOSSIER":null,"NUMARCHIVE":null,"OBSERVATIONDOSSIER":null,"ORGANISATION_ID":70007,"STATUTDOSSIER":null,"TYPEDOSSIER":null}]

Comment: @LucaFabbri even with those few information it should work and log the properties but i dont knew why it didn't

Comment: @charlietfl it works fine in other example

Comment: Should be `const doss = await req.json();` . Then use `map()` on `this.state.dossier` to iterate the array for output

Comment: It worked in componentDidMount, but it gaves me an error inside the render methode:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'CODE' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Client extends Component {
  state = {
    dossier: []
  };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const req = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/dossier/EQDOM/D200074`);

    //Remove JSON.stringofy since it will convert your object or array into a string;
    // const doss = await JSON.stringify(req);
    this.setState({ dossier: doss });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {this.state.dossier.length > 0 && (
          <div>
            <span>code: {this.state.dossier.map(data => data['code' || 'CODE'])}</span>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Client;
```

Since you have the Data Like this:

```
{  
    "ID":34404198,
    "AGENCE":"1.1.9.",
    "CODE":"EQDOM/D200074",
    "DTCLOTURE":null,
    "DTCONSTITUTIONDP":null,
    "DTCREATION":null,
    "DT_INIT":"2018-11-01T07:36:39.000Z",
    "DT_MAJ":"2018-12-03T23:00:00.000Z",
    "DTMISEAJOUR":null,
    "DTRECEPTIONPIECES":null,
    "DTREMISEDOSSIER":null,
    "UTILISATEUR_ID":568574,
    "INDBCENTRALISATIONAUTO":null,
    "INDCLOTURE":null,
    "NOTEDOSSIER":null,
    "NUMARCHIVE":null,
    "OBSERVATIONDOSSIER":null,
    "ORGANISATION_ID":70007,
    "STATUTDOSSIER":null,
    "TYPEDOSSIER":null
}
```

The `CODE` will be accessible only on the first index of `this.state.dossier` now you need to iterate over that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the data is an array with the object you're looking for in it.
You should access it with this:

```
this.state.dossier[0].CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this for the response.

```
=> this.state.dossier[0].CODE
```

Because your is like array of object and the code is CODE typecasting